What happened to the other eight Ringwraiths?
We see Eowen kill the Witch King, but it's much less clear what happens to the other eight, at least as far as I remember.  Are they destroyed as well when Sauron is destroyed?

Dupe of What happened to the 13 Rings of Power that survived the War of the Ring?.

@Paulie_D - Top answer there mentions that they were "disollut[ed]". Being dissolved doesn't sound terribly survivable, tbh.

The remaining Ringwraiths had all been present at Cirith Gorgor, facing down the host led by Aragorn.  When Frodo put on the One Ring and tried to claim its power, Sauron immediately detected him.  The dark lord summoned back the Nazgul on their flying mounts, the swiftest and strongest of his minions, but Frodo's affray with Gollum was brief and over well before they arrived at Mount Doom.  They dissipated like flaming streamers in the fiery clouds that erupted from the mountain after the One Ring was consumed by the Cracks of Doom.

Fire belched from its riven summit. The skies burst into thunder seared with lightning. Down like lashing whips fell a torrent of black rain. And into the heart of the storm, with a cry that pierced all other sounds, tearing the clouds asunder, the Nazgûl came, shooting like flaming bolts, as caught in the fiery ruin of hill and sky they crackled, withered, and went out.

